# How to implement an enum in C++

Tags: c++, enums

I am trying to create an enum in C++ and use it in a class. But I am getting the following error:

```
TestClass.cpp:65:49: error: 'TestNameSpace::TestClass::Buttons' is not a class or namespace:Buttons::Right
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

TestClass.h:

```
namespace TestNameSpace
{
    class TestClass
    {
    public:
        enum Buttons { Left, Right, Up, Down, Select, None };
        TestClass();
        ~TestClass();
    private:
        Buttons getButtonType(int buttonValue);
    };
}
```

TestClass.cpp:

```
#include "AirController.h"
namespace TestNameSpace
{
    Buttons TestClass::getButtonType(int buttonValue)
    {
        if (buttonValue < 50)   return Buttons::Right;
        if (buttonValue < 195)  return Buttons::Up;
        if (buttonValue < 380)  return Buttons::Down;
        if (buttonValue < 555)  return Buttons::Left;
        if (buttonValue < 790)  return Buttons::Select;
        return Buttons::None;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to `#include "TestClass.h"` in TestClass.cpp. Also, you need `TestClass::Buttons TestClass::getButtonType...` because `Buttons` is inside `TestClass`.

Comment: Or, alternatively, you could use a trailing return type: `auto TestClass::getButtonType(int buttonValue) -> Buttons {... }`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks for the reply mate.  I have updated the sample to include the header.  I tried prefixing with the class name but it made no difference.

Comment: Can you paste a link to the code with those fixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With *classical* enums, members are accessed **without** mentioning the name of the enum type. In other words, enum members live in the name space the enum lives in, not inside the enum.

That means, remove `Buttons::` in front of the enum values:

```
TestClass::Buttons TestClass::getButtonType(int buttonValue)
{
    if (buttonValue < 50)   return Right;
    if (buttonValue < 195)  return Up;
    if (buttonValue < 380)  return Down;
    if (buttonValue < 555)  return Left;
    if (buttonValue < 790)  return Select;
    return None;
}
```

The name of the enum `Buttons::` needs to be prefixed when you use the more *modern* way of declaring enums, that is "scoped enums" or "enum classes":

```
enum class Buttons { Left, Right, Up, Down, Select, None };
```

Then, you avoid name clashes with other stuff having the same name like your enum members.

Answer (score 3):

[I got your code to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8175e0c926c4e89e) by simply adding `TestClass::` qualification. That being said, you probably wanted `enum class`.

You need to `#include "TestClass.h"` in order to make it visible in that translation unit, when you split it across files.

Answer (score -1):

The enum definition may be placed outside of the class definition, if this is not a design requirement:

```
enum Buttons { Left, Right, Up, Down, Select, None };
```

then you access it like this:

```
Buttons::Left
```

Comment: And? I think OP knows this. Your edit is false; a standard `enum` puts all its members in the enclosing namespace, you seem to be talking about `enum class`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Placing the enum outside of the class definition works, so I think it does answer the question. the OP does not say the enum has to be within the class defintion.

Comment: No, it doesn't "work", it accomplishes a completely different thing. His code  places the enum inside of the class, and that's enough to assume that he wants to have it inside of the class.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz the OP asks for a solution, and does not pose any restrictions. In my opinion, it is you who is incorrect by making assumptions on what he might or might not want.

Comment: The main problem with this suggestion is that all the enumeration identifiers will be dumped into the namespace scope, so it doesn't scale that well if any other enumeration wants to have its own `None` or whatever.  If the enumerations are relevant to several classes/functions in the namespace, and not logically strongly bound to a specific class, it may make sense to move them to namespace scope, possibly making the identifiers more "unique".  Or, `enum class` provides other options.

Comment: @TonyD nice point, I did no think about that. I can see it might not be the best solution, given that limitation. Nonetheless, I see nothing so wrong with this approach to deserve such downvoting.

Comment: @BlunT: agreed - seems excessive - a counter from me.  `Buttons::Left` is only valid from C++11 BTW /- that may have raised an eyebrow or two, and *"should"* was a bit strong, perhaps "could"?

Comment: @TonyD thank you, and thanks for the suggestion. I edited the sentence to remove the 'should'.